# JavaScript: Whats the difference between document.getElementById and accessing DOM elements by declaring them in variables?

Tags: javascript, html

Both of the methods output the same results to console, is there a difference?

```js
        const test1 = mainDiv; 

        console.log('test1 ', test1); //<div id="mainDiv">TEST</div>

        const test2 = document.getElementById('mainDiv');

        console.log('test2  ', test2); //<div id="mainDiv">TEST</div>
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">TEST</div>
```

Comment: They are in the same scope

Comment: try that with `id="main-div"` or with `id="location"`

Comment: The good practice is to use getElementById. Avoid the global created by the browser (it can be redeclared in other scopes)

Comment: What is this `const test1 = mainDiv;` way of accessing DOM elements called?